# Restructure one dimensional array into variable length two dimension array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to convert a one dimensional array into a two dimensional array where the length of the rows are different depending on the maximum number of columns which is supplied as an argument. I basically want to include every nth index till the end of array is reached or max number of columns are done whatever happens earlier. So for the following input:

> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
> 19, 20]
>
> columns = 7

I want the following output:

> [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19]
>
> [2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
>
> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]

I have tried the following code but it only works for few values:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];


function getOutput(arr, columns) {

  var rows = Math.ceil(arr.length / columns);
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    tmp = [];
    for (var j = 0, index = i; j < columns; j++) {
      if (index < arr.length)
        tmp.push(arr[index]);
      index += rows;
    }
    res.push(tmp);
  }
  return res;

}
console.log(getOutput(array, 7))
```

JSFiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/varunsharma38/fwfz4veo/4/

I do not understand what I am missing. Although, I would not mind using some libraries, I would prefer a vanilla JS based solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your current output gives the output you wanted. So, what's the issue?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest as I had stated in the question, this works for some values. For example if you change the value to 8, it will still have maximum 7 columns only

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `array#reduce`.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], 
    columns = 7,
    result = arr.reduce((r,v,i,a) => {
      var index = i% (Math.ceil(a.length/columns));
      r[index] = r[index] || [];
      r[index].push(v);
      return r;
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That fails if you choose a number higher than 7 for the columns

Comment: Try changing the number of columns to anything higher than 7 and you'll see the result